# Are java inbuilt method good in performance?

Tags: java, arrays, performance, optimization, methods

I used `for` loop to initialise an array with default value. And I also used `Arrays.fill` for performance comparison. In every test case for own `for` loop is faster than `Arrays.fill` method

If inbuilt method is not giving good performance then why many developer use inbuilt method.

I am not expert in CP so please suggest

Comment: How have you measured the performance? Show us the code.

Comment: Other than that, readability >> performance most of the time. And micro optimization comes last, usually the problem is with general algorithm.

Comment: 99.999% chance that they way you measured is wrong. See [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/504103/2711488)

Comment: Agree with @Holger. So that linked question may give the best answer to yours. `Arrays.fill()` uses a simple loop, so unless the method call is costly — *very* unlikely — you won’t notice any performance difference in the end.